# Format to return data from C# Web Api to Angular ng-repeat

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to return back from my API a list of all the products that were updated by the API. The API is called by some AngularJS code that uses a promise that returns data. In what format should I build a string of Products on the server-side that can be interpreted by Angular on the client-side?

C#

```
 string results = "WidgetA - $12, WidgetB - $22 - ....":
 return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="model in data ">
    {{model.ProductName  + '  ' + model.ProductPrice + ' imported'  }}
</div>
```

Angular

```
.then(function (data) {
    // promise fulfilled
    if (data === '') {
        alert("No Data Returned");
    } else {
        // Data is returned
        // How to get it in model that can be iterated over
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to end up with a list a Products and Prices that were updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning a string.  Which is just, well, a string.  But you *want* to return an array of something.

So return an array of something:

```
var results = new List<Product>
{
    new Product("WidgetA", 12.0),
    new Product("WidgetB", 22.0)
};
return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<Product>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
```

(Assuming you've created a `Product` class, of course.  Construct that however you like.)

Then client-side:

```
.then(function (data) {
    // promise fulfilled
    if (data.length === 0) {
        alert("No Data Returned");
    } else {
        // "data" is an array of products here
    }
}
```

Structured and defined models are generally easier to work with than string blobs that would need to be parsed and interpreted anywhere you want to use them.

Comment: Thanks David! That makes a lot of sense.Given that array returned as data how would I iterate over that in Angular in the ng-repeat?

Comment: @webworm: I'm not *entirely* an expert on Angular, but I suspect the view would just be binding to the model, no?  I found a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/RkykR/  Basically `data` is your array, just as `m` is an array in that example.